# Connection string open but doesn't proceed

Tags: android, json, inputstream, httpconnection

I am trying to convert the connection string to buffer input stream and then to string so that I can change it to json format but while debugging the program doesn't proceed after
 `in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());` 
and directly goes to return statement. Please help.
I followed this article : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_json_parser.htm

```
public String makeServiceCall(String input_url)
{
    String response=null;
    InputStream in=null;
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    try {

        URL url= new URL(input_url);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in,"UTF-8"));
        String inputLine = "";
        while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(inputLine);
        }
        response = sb.toString();

    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "MalformedURLException: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    catch (ProtocolException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "ProtocolException: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "IOException: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return response;
}
```

Comment: I bet you are getting an Exception ... I bet on NOMTException ...

Comment: How to resolve it ?

Comment: By learning how to debug

Answer (score 0):

String str="example"
StringBuffer sbf = new StringBuffer();

//convert String Buffer to  bytes 
 byte[] bytes = sbf.toString().getBytes();

InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);